# Timelapse (1/6 fps) from slo-mo (240 fps) with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, frame-rate, timelapse, slowmotion

I recorded slo-mo video on an iPhone SE (2) by mistake instead of timelapse.

I know there's a lot of answers to this question here, but I'm trying again and again and always something's wrong (like a video that has a correct total no. of frames, but lasts 3 hours and is basically a freeze :D )
My recent command was

> ffmpeg -i IMG_2174.MOV -vf framestep=1440,setpts=N/120/TB -c:v libx264
> -preset slow -crf 22 -an -r 30 IMG_2174.timelapse.MOV

but it resulted in a one-second-long video, so way over-timelapsed. Should be several seconds IINM. The source video is 30 minutes long @240fps, 17GB.
Thx.

Comment: Is 240 actual fps of the input or the recording fps? If the latter, what's the playback fps (=input fps)?

Comment: I guess I understand what you're asking about, but where can I get this info? Should MediaInfo tell me this? It shows `Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 240.188 FPS
Minimum frame rate                       : 120.000 FPS
Maximum frame rate                       : 266.667 FPS`

Comment: However, I seem to find the right parameters, see below.

Comment: OK, when you say "slo-mo" I was expecting the playback rate to be lower than the recording rate (The vfr of the file is the playback rate) and I thought you might be interested in getting 1/6 fps wrt to the recording rate. But, never mind

Answer (score 0):

This command seems to do the trick:

> ffmpeg -i IMG_2174.MOV -vf framestep=1440,setpts=N/30/TB -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -an -r 30 IMG_2174.timelapse.MOV

Comment: Explain why and which param is causing the work

Comment: The change is from N/120/TB to N/30/TB. As for explaining, I'd like to hear it myself :)

Comment: refer how an answer is given https://stackoverflow.com/a/71682062/5954410

Comment: @AbhishekRaj I don't really know what you're after...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the explanation for OP's self-answer.

```
ffmpeg -i IMG_2174.MOV 
       -vf framestep=1440,setpts=N/30/TB 
       -r 30 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -an IMG_2174.timelapse.MOV
```

Given input video at 240 fps cfr:

1. `framestep=1440` keep every 1440th frame, yielding 240/1440 = 1/6 fps
2. `setpts=N/30/TB` speeds up the video by x180 (30 / 1/6)
3. `-r 30` output option: match the new pts interval set above

For a vfr video, `framestep=1440` likely results in incorrect timing (though on the average correct). For such video, replace the `framestep` filter with `fps=1/6` filter so it picks the frames based on pts rather than frame count.

[edit note: iPhone's slo-mo recording does keep 240fps cfr so the OP's solution is 100% correct, edited down just to mention a vfr-correct approach]

Comment: Thanks, I've given it a try. However, the result of your command is as follows: https://pastebin.com/tdTT7rNr, and it's not as expected. While the MediaInfo for the result of my (framestep) command is: https://pastebin.com/Kx8Yh7wz

Comment: You're absolutely correct. My bad. As the edited post suggests, your solution is 100% correct because iPhone does record at 240 fps cfr.